# Try to compile a java program that uses jsoup package on Mac

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to compile a Java program that uses jSoup. 
Name of Program: WebCrawler.java

I was having issues with getting the program to compile. Thanks to Arvind(user below) that works. However when I `java WebCrawler`. I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WebCrawler/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WebCrawler.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Is that because of my classpath?

Answer (score 0):

**To compile (on linux):**

```
export CLASSPATH=jsoup-1.8.1.jar
javac WebCrawler.java
```

or

```
javac -cp jsoup-1.8.1.jar WebCrawler.java
```